# Insert fig into excel workbook using a for loop and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, xlsxwriter

I have created a for loop where I am writing a dataframe to an excel file and then plot the datafame and saving the image as a png file. Within the loop, i would like to add each of the saved images to each excel worksheet. I know how to do this outside the loop using openplyx but that would be way too much unnecessary code.

Any ideas of how to insert the figs into each of the worksheets within the workbook?

Here is my code:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('america.xlsx')
countrylist = countrylist.set_index(['COUNTRY_NAME'])
for i in countrylist.index:
    var = i
    test = likes[likes['COUNTRY_NAME'].map(str.strip)== str((var))]
    test.rename(columns={'YEAR': 'Year'}, inplace=True)
    test.to_excel(writer, var, index=False, columns = ['Year', 'Area', 'Region'])
    ax = test.plot.bar('Year', ['Area', 'Region'], align = 'center', alpha=0.5, title=var)
    fig = ax.get_figure()
    folder = 'ra/'
    fig.savefig(folder + var + '.png')
```